# Matlab Legend Rejecting Cell Array of Strings for Input

Tags: matlab

I have what I believe is a valid cell array of strings (prn_leg) that I would like to input as the legend at the end of my plot.

```
prn_leg = 

  Columns 1 through 6

'3'    '7'    '8'    '9'    '16'    '19'

  Columns 7 through 10

'23'    '27'    '31'    '32'
```

However, when I attempt

```
legend(prn_leg)
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Error updating Legend.

 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

> In defaulterrorcallback (line 12)
  In TEC_plotting (line 46)
```

and a blank legend appears in the figure.

I've looked all over solutions and none of them seem to work.

Thanks very much!

Tom

Comment: What does `class(prn_leg)` return when called right before `legend(prn_leg)`?

Comment: both  `class(prn_leg)` and `whos prn_leg` return that it is a cell.  From all I can tell it is a cell of strings with each string in its own cell.  I don't see a difference in the output if I define it as suggested: `prin_leg = {'3','7',...};`  It appears the same to me.

Comment: That was exactly what I expected it to be from the given output in the question. So the answer of @bern won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved my problem.  I think it's worth posting it here to say that it wasn't a problem with legend or the cell array of strings I was trying to use.

The issue was that I generated my plot in a loop which occasionally contained empty cells.  I removed the empty cells in my legend cell array, but the plot still contained the empty array---which resulted in dimension (0x1) mismatch with the legend (1x12).  I fixed this by adding a condition that checked if the data array was empty in each loop and only plotted it if it was not.  This resulted in 1xN dimensions for the plotted data, which is then compatible with a 1xN legend input.

```
if ~isempty(Y)
    scatter(X,Y,10,C(pp,:))
    hold on

    prn_leg{pp} = unique(dta.prn{ss}(idx));

end

prn_leg = cellfun(@num2str,prn_leg,'uni',0);
legend(prn_leg)
```

I hope this is useful to someone else.  Thanks everyone for your replies!

Answer (score 1):

the `legend()` function expects a column separated list of strings or a cell array of strings, not a vector of strings. Therefore the easiest way to fix this is to change your input from a vector into a cell array, and then legend should work, where each element is:

```
prin_leg{1} = '3'; prin_leg{2} = '7', etc.
```

or per comments more efficiently:

```
prin_leg = {'3','7',...};
```

Comment: Or just `prin_leg = {'3', '7',` ... `}`.

Comment: @horchler yes that is more efficient, I will add to my answer, I just wanted to show how to access the elements in the cell array as well.

Comment: But the OP has a cell array of strings as evidenced by 16 total characters in 10 columns.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is a vector of strings in Matlab?

Comment: a vector of string is what the OP presented, in matlab that would be `p = ['3','7',...]`

Comment: The OP presented a cell-array and this has been confirmed in the comments of the question. Try doing the assignment `p = ['3','7']` and it won't provide the result as in the OP's question. It concatenates all the *strings* into one single string, a *vector of `char`* with size `1x2`. What you can do to have the strings separate in different rows is `p = ['3';'7']` which will you give a *matrix of `char`* with size `2x1`. The problem is that the length of the strings must be equal. So it is not possible to have 3 and 16 in the same matrix without a space before/after the 3.

Comment: But look at the given excerpt in the OP's question. It is organised in **separate columns** which cannot be achieved with `p = ['3','7']` but with a cell-array.